# Change a variable's accessibility during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wish to know if there is room for changing a variable's accessibility during runtime in Unity C#? The reason I want this is to hide unnecessary public variables when my script uses another state. I tried some dynamic variables, but I get errors that it can't be found. 
I have that `springDistance` but I want to use it only when the state of the `trapType` is `springOut`. 
Some code:

```
public class SpringTrap : MonoBehaviour
{
private Transform objectToMove;
// Use this for initialization
public enum TypeOfTrap
{
    springOut
}
[Tooltip("Set the type of trap here to use.")]
public TypeOfTrap trapType = TypeOfTrap.springOut;

public float springDistance;

void Start ()
{
    objectToMove = transform.FindChild("ObjectsToAnimate");
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        //if the player has entered the danger zone
        switch (trapType)
        {
            case TypeOfTrap.springOut:

                break;

        }
    }
}
IEnumerator SpringOut(float springDistance)
{
    float deltaDist = 0.0f;
    while(deltaDist < springDistance)
    {
        objectToMove.position += 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your question is quite vague with no example, so I'm really taking a stab in the dark, but have you looked at the [SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) attribute?

Comment: I did but it didn't solve my problem, I might have used it the wrong way. I update my question with some code.

Comment: You mean you want to hide them in the editor (inspector) if they are currently not relevant for the script so that they don't get changed unnecessarily?

Comment: Exactly. Hide if unnecessary.

Comment: Have a look at custom editor for doing stuff like that. This is an example that actually should be quite similar to what you want to do: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/417837/change-inspector-variables-depending-on-enum.html

Comment: Yes, very similar, but also very complicated :D If there is no other means to this end, I might as well just use a tooltip to notify meself that tempering with the given variable is unnecessary.

Comment: No, I don't think there is another, simpler way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help in that case. You might want to convert your comment to an answer as it indeed would solve the problem.

Comment: Did that. Yes, doing this for a small thing is probably overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulation of the inspector is done with custom editor scripts. There you can display things, e.g. based on conditions.

Here is an example that does a very similar thing to the requested (displaying different things based on an enum field):
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/417837/change-inspector-variables-depending-on-enum.html

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do what you are trying to achieve is to create an abstract trap class and then subclass different types of traps.

The abstract trap class handles collisions and then calls the abstract method Trigger.

```
public abstract class Trap : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            Trigger(other.transform);
    } 

    protected abstract void Trigger (Transform victim);
}
```

A spring trap can then be easily created by extending Trap and overriding the Trigger method.

```
public class SpringTrap : Trap {

    public float SpringDistance;

    protected override void Trigger (Transform victim) {
        victim.position += Vector3.up * SpringDistance;
    }
}
```

Now you don't have to worry about hiding irrelevant properties based on trap type because the only properties that will appear in the inspector are those you add to that variation of trap.